# Exercise for ordering pizzas with user input

Tags: java

I've only been learning Java for two weeks, and I had to complete this task as part of my course. My instructor could not give specific feedback as answer file is already provided, the code works but I am just wondering what some of you might think of my code if it can be refined. It's a basic pizza ordering program.

The requirements were:

able to specify pizzas one at a time using an loop.
loop can end or not based on input.
order viauser input using the Scanner class.
format currency with NumberFormat
Thank you for your time and wisdom.

```
import java.util.Scanner;  
import java.text.NumberFormat; 
        
public class PizzaOrder {
   
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //defining and initialising variables.
        NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int pizzaquantity=0;
        int numberoftoppings = 0;
        double toppingtotalprice =0;
        char ordermore = 'n';
        double runningtotal = 0;
        final double stp = 1.0, ltp = 1.5, ftp = 2.0;
        final double s = 8.0, l = 11.0, f = 14.0;
        
        //using a do while loop, because condition to stop is at the end.        
        do{
            
            System.out.println("Please place the order for your pizza.");
            System.out.println("Size (s = small, l = large, f = family):");
            char pizzasize = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
            //if else-else if nested inside loop
            //one iteration of the conditional statement for pizza size type.
            //number format is applied to every iteration of cost.
            if (pizzasize == 's')
            {
                System.out.println("Number of toppings?:");
                numberoftoppings = keyboard.nextInt();
                toppingtotalprice = (numberoftoppings * stp);
                System.out.println("Pizza Quantity:");
                pizzaquantity = keyboard.nextInt();
                runningtotal = (pizzaquantity * toppingtotalprice * s);
                System.out.println("Cost is: " + nf.format(runningtotal));
                
                
            }
            else if (pizzasize == 'l')
            {
                System.out.println("Number of toppings?:");
                numberoftoppings = keyboard.nextInt();
                toppingtotalprice = (numberoftoppings * ltp);
                System.out.println("Pizza Quantity:");
                pizzaquantity = keyboard.nextInt();
                runningtotal = (pizzaquantity * toppingtotalprice * l);
                System.out.println("Cost is:" + nf.format(runningtotal));
                
                
            }
            else if   (pizzasize == 'f')
            {
                System.out.println("Number of toppings?:");
                numberoftoppings = keyboard.nextInt();
                toppingtotalprice = (numberoftoppings * ftp);
                System.out.println("Pizza Quantity:");
                pizzaquantity = keyboard.nextInt();
                runningtotal = (pizzaquantity * toppingtotalprice * l);
                System.out.println("Cost is:" + nf.format(runningtotal));
                
                
            }
            else 
            {
            }        
                System.out.println("Order more? (y/n):");
                ordermore = keyboard.next().charAt(0);
        }
        while (ordermore != 'n');
         
        
        System.out.println("Total cost is: " + nf.format(runningtotal += runningtotal));
        System.out.println("Thank you for your order!");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Your title is far too generic. Please follow the guidelines: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
```

Don't shorten names just because you can, it makes the code harder to read and maintain.

```java
final double s = 8.0, l = 11.0, f = 14.0;
```

***Perfect*** example of that. The more descriptive the names are, the better. Length should not be of any concern.

---

```java
double toppingtotalprice =0;
```

A `double` is still a floating point. For money, you always want to use `BigDecimal`, or an `int` as the smallest unit your money has (Cents for example).

---

```java
char ordermore = 'n';
```

Should mot likely be a boolean.

---

```java
        //using a do while loop, because condition to stop is at the end.        
        do{
```

You can use a `while` here, though.

---

I'll skip the rest of your code and directly skip to the part that you've been waiting for: That works, but is bad design.

Note that in the following examples I'm still using `double` for simplicity, you should use something else.

Let's start with the fact that you have a lot of repetition, extract common parts into a function which accepts parameters to parameterize it. For example:

```java
private static final double inputPizza(double pizzaSizePrice, double toppingPricel) {
    System.out.println("Number of toppings?:");
    numberoftoppings = keyboard.nextInt();
    toppingtotalprice = (numberoftoppings * toppingPrice);
    System.out.println("Pizza Quantity:");
    pizzaquantity = keyboard.nextInt();
    return (pizzaquantity * toppingtotalprice * pizzaSizePrice);
}
```

That already reduces repetition a lot.

Now, we're going to encapsulate our information in a class of their own:

```java
public class PizzaCosts {
    protected double price;
    protected double toppingPrice;
    
    public PizzaPriceValues(double price, double toppingPrice) {
        super();
        
        this.price = price;
        this.toppingPrice = toppingPrice;
    }
    
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    
    public double getToppingPrice() {
        return toppingPrice;
    }
}
```

And in our main function:

```java
PizzaCosts smallPizzaCosts = new PizzaCosts(8.0d, 1.0d);
PizzaCosts mediumPizzaCosts = new PizzaCosts(11.0d, 1.5d);
PizzaCosts largePizzaCosts = new PizzaCosts(14.0d, 2.d);
```

That groups the values nicely together and makes it easier to read. Now let's go one step further, we'll put them into a `Map` to access them dynamically based on user-input:

```java
Map<String, PizzaCosts> pizzaCosts = new HashMap<>();
pizzaCosts.put("s", new PizzaCosts(8.0d, 1.0d));
pizzaCosts.put("m", new PizzaCosts(11.0d, 1.5d));
pizzaCosts.put("l", new PizzaCosts(14.0d, 2.0d));

PizzaCosts selectedPizzaCosts = pizzaCosts.get(keyboard.next());

if (selectedPizzaCosts != null) {
    runningTotal = runningTotal + inputPizza(pizzaCosts);
} else {
    // Invalid selection
}
```

Now that's a lot nicer, and should be enough to get you started further.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that I observed was the duplication. Whatever the size of a pizza you have to ask for the same things. You should figure out how to remove that duplication of code.

Comment: Thanks @pacmaninbw for the edit, much better than my hard words. +1

Comment: Word usage, it should have been hit rather than hurt.